# how to secure the server ip, controllers and actions in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, security, url, web

I want to protect the ip address and url of rails app
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/controller/action
are accessible, i want to protect these urls and controller actions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the help section - stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Unfortunately, this is a very low quality question.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add a before filter like mentioned below

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "foo", password: "secret", only: :name_of_action_you_want_to_restrict

  def some method
  ...
  end

end
```

In this manner you will have a basic authentication for your pages you want to have. 
Also if you want to restrict access at a higher level, you will have to go with rails authentication using users and sessions controller.

Hope this helps

Cheers !

Comment: this is for internal rails application, I want to authenticate the user on Apache level. The reason is that app is deployed on server and I want to protect every url of this app, if someone tries to access the app, it will ask authentication on apache, not with internal rails application.